# Apple.com Search like Icon and Search Pop Out

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

I am trying to build an apple.com like search icon and I have read most of the other posts about this.
I am using css for the smooth transition and on and off click search expansion. (no js)
The current problem I am having is I only want to only show the search icon and none of the input box (no background color or border) when the box is contracted. (I want to see the search icon and nothing else)

It is a bit difficult for me since the search icon is placed as the background to the search bar.

Any suggestions how to accomplish this? I tried to use js to create and hide a separate search icon and overlay it on the input bar, but its getting messy and it is not a great solution.

Please let me know!

Fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/simonzhu91/go17ab2x/

```
.search {
  width:360px;
  position:relative; top:2px; 
  padding:8px 5px 8px 30px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  background:white url(http://i.imgur.com/lFkqn.png) left center no-repeat;
}


#search input {
  width: 30px !important;
  -moz-transition: width 0.5s ease-out !important;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-out !important;
  transition: width 0.5s ease-out !important;
  border: 0 !important;
  outline: 0 !important;
  -webkit-appearance:none !important;
  -moz-appearance:none !important;
  appearance:none !important;
}

#search input:focus {
  width: 200px !important;
  -moz-transition: width 0.5s ease-out !important;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-out !important;
  transition: width 0.5s ease-out !important;
  border: default !important;
  background: default !important;
}
```

Will AC the first working solution =)

Comment: I only see the icon in the fiddle. What am I missing?

Comment: You can slightly see the outline of the search input box. In addition, the background color of the input box is white. My navbar is gray, so the input box's white color shows up. It's a bit hard to see since the fiddle color is white as well.

Comment: just make the search icon a label tied to the input so that clicking the icon focuses the input; no JS needed.

Comment: Could you show me on fiddle?

Comment: css is up to you but here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/go17ab2x/1/

Comment: You can still see the border of the input box and the background white is still there. This does not solve my problem of hiding the input box.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/simonzhu91/go17ab2x/2/ is a closer solution, but the spacing is not correct. The label is shifted over by the input box.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63371/discussion-between-simonzhu-and-mathletics).